# Softkeyboard pops up automatically first time the webview loads

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

Apparently there are no editboxes or anything which needs a keyboard on the webpage either.

and this dos'nt work either even on user interaction event.

```
public void onUserInteraction()
    {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(webView.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
```

This is the log from logcat.

http://pastebin.com/i5q0axk9

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3x9QMTm8 And this happens only on samsung galaxy device

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is how to open URL then you try this and it is the tested code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The issue is not opening the webview or anything related to it, its just that the keyboard pops up automatically which i dont want to

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml

use **android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"**

e.g

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Worked for me, Hope helps you also.

Comment: it dint, i think samsung is doing something wierd, IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED
AxT9SipMgr.setInputMode - from : 1, to : 1